# server error in '/' application. resource not found (when modified)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, tfs

I have a MVC application which is currently checked in through TFS. When i try to run the website, it is working well. However, whenever i do some code changes on the main page which is an .cshtml file, it showing an error "Server Error in "/" application. Resource not found."

I've tried to clean the solution then build again but i am still encountering that error.

I tried to undo pending changes on that .cshtml file. Then it is running well again.

Am I missing something in here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

1. clean solution and rebuild solution
2. restart visual studio
3. get specific version with latest and overwrite everything (be sure nothing is checked out)

Comment: But my changes will be overwritten when i get specific version

Comment: Hi. good for you :) please mark my answer as the solution .. Sometimes step 1 works. If step 1 doesnt work try step 2.. and if step 2 doesnt work.. step 3 is your friend.

Comment: Yeah, i always do step 1 but wasn't aware that step 2 would be my savior :) Thanks again!